# SQL AVG from one table joining name from another

Tags: mysql

I am new to SQL

I got 2 tables. Although 2 ID columns could map with each other, but I don't know how to combine the name of these 2 different attributes "Dep ID" and "Dept ID Dep" Therefore, I couldn't use the solution posted in StackOverflow.

```
[employees]
Dep ID | SALARY
1      |  500
2      |  200
1      |  300
2      | 1000
2      |  400
3      |  200
3      |  300
```

```
[departments]
Dept ID Dep| Dept Name
1          | Volcano
2          | ShootingStar
3          | Tsunami
```

In the end, I want to create a list looks like:

```
Dept Name   | Average Salary
Volcano     | $$$
ShootingStar| $$
Tsunami     | $$$$
```

I tried various ways and hunting hints in stackoverflow for sub queries/inner join features but still can't get it.

Here is my code:

```
-- mapping DEPT ID with NAME + average salary by DEPT --
select E.DEP_ID, D.DEP_NAME,  (select AVG(SALARY) from EMPLOYEES group by DEP_ID) as AVG_S
from EMPLOYEES E, DEPARTMENTS D
where E.DEP_ID = D.DEPT_ID_DEP
group by DEP_ID, DEP_NAME;
```

Please help!

Thank you very much.

Comment: You can simply join the two tables and then get the Avg

Comment: could you tell me how to do? I have tried many times

Comment: @UXBackpacker see answers to the duplicate question for a solution via join and avg.